# Homebrew to install Homebank

Tags: macos, mac, install, homebrew

I'm running the latest version of MacOS Big Sur 11.6.5.

I think Homebank is properly installed after verification but is listed with packages and not cask.

Both brew and Homebank are up to date and berw doctor returns perfectly normal no error message.

How do I get Homebank to appear in my applications folder to launch the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebank seems to be a Unix-style binary and gets installed into `$(brew --prefix)/bin`. You can run it directly from Terminal with `homebank`.

Answer (score 0):

How about [gtk-mac-integration](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GTK/OSX/Integration?action=show&redirect=Projects%2FGTK%2B%2FOSX%2FIntegration)?